# How to use new RT index with existing large MySQL table with Sphinx / Manticore?

Tags: sphinx, manticore-search

I have a large (200Gb) MySQL table which is constantly grows with new rows. Is it possible to create an RT index in Manticore and fill it with existing data from this table? Or is it possible to alter existing RT index with new `charset_table` and be available to search through all the table data, now only added after altering the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution! [Attaching a plain index to an RT index.](https://docs.manticoresearch.com/3.2.0/html/sphinxql_reference/attach_index_syntax.html)

At first, create a plain index with source, then attach it to RT index and populate the RT index with new incoming data. In my case it took near 2 hours for plain indexing and less than one second for attaching.